# How to use SetAction in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to whitelist my app on Android 6.0 or greater. I have seen Android code to do this, but it doesn't translate in Xamarin and Xamarin documentation only tells you that SetAction takes a string as an argument, and then a link to Android documentation which doesn't end up being the same.

Here's the Android code that Xamarin will not accept

```
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
```

It doesn't like Settings. I've read the Xamarin documentation which says that SetAction() takes a string arg, and that's all they say and point you to Android documentation.

Note, I am calling this in a javascript interface class and I tried this but it doesn't work

```
class MyJSInterface : Java.Lang.Object
    {
    Context context;
    public MyJSInterface(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }
    [Export]
    [JavascriptInterface]
    public void SetDozeOptimization()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "launch optimization", ToastLength.Short).Show();

            setDozeComplete = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            String packageName = context.PackageName;
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            if (pm.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
                intent.SetAction("ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS");
            else
            {
                intent.SetAction("ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS");
                intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + packageName));
            }
            context.StartActivity(intent);
        }

}
```

So what is the correct syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Android.Provider.Settings.ActionRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations`:

- android.settings.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

`Android.Provider.Settings.ActionIgnoreBatteryOptimizationSettings`:

- android.settings.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS

Example:

```
intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations);
intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionIgnoreBatteryOptimizationSettings);
```

Comment: I didn't test because that was not the question, The question was about syntax, and Visual Studio says that's the right syntax. Thank you. Marked as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you are looking for:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String packageName = context.PackageName;
PowerManager pm(PowerManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);

if (!pm.IsIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
{
    intent.SetAction(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionRequestIgnoreBatteryOptimizations);
    intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("package:" + packageName));
    StartActivity(intent);
}
```